# Why is innerHTML wiping the values on these input fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am creating form which can add custom fields to. I was originally using .innerHTML to add these additional forms. When I added new forms, any values in the previous ones were wiped.

So the html looks like this:

```
<button id="add"></button>
<div id = "outer_div"></div>
```

The initial javascript looked like this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#add", function()
  {

   getElementById("outer_div").innerHTML +='<input></input>';

  });
```

Say you add two fields. You write something in the first field. You press the `#add` button. What you wrote in the first field is now cleared.

I decided to use jquery and it no longer had this problem:

```
$(document).on("click", "#add", function()
  {

   $("#outer_div").append('<input></input>');

  });
```

Why?

Comment: Important to understand that the  **value property** isn't stored in **value attribute** when user changes input. The attribute never changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because of the "+=" operator:

`getElementById("outer_div").innerHTML +='<input></input>';`

What is happening is you are resetting the complete value of innerHTML every time, which effectively removes the existing fields and re-adds them.

The reason this does not happen with jQuery is that underneath the hood, jQuery is using the Javascript `.appendChild` function to directly insert the new elements in the DOM.

The pure javascript version for your example would be something like this:

```
var inpElem = document.createElement("input");

document.getElementById("outer_div").appendChild(inpElem);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the values written into the fields aren't considered to be a part of the existing HTML. So when you append the new HTML to the form, the values are lost because as far as innerHTML is concerned, they don't exist anyway. A probable fix can be to temporarily store all the form's values in variables, then once the new HTML is appended to the old, reassign them to the proper fields.